# udp socket program in c for linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, udpclient

```
int acceptSocket;
char buf[100];
long sentbytes;
socklen_t len;
int port = 18227;

int CreateSocket()
{
    long rc;
    struct sockaddr_in addr, client;

       // Socket creation for UDP
       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)
       {
         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");
         return 1;
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Socket started!\n");
       }

     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port=htons(port);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)
     {
       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
     }

     while(rc!=-1)
         {
         len =sizeof(client);
         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }

         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );

            makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
                makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
                makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
          }

       close(acceptSocket);
       return 0;
     }

int main()
{
     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 0;
}

//API for sending the data to the client.
void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 XcpPort,  Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )
{
    struct sockaddr_in client;

        if ((long)XcpPort==port){
                sentbytes = sendto(acceptSocket,(char*)pBytes,(long)numBytes,0, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));
        }
        XcpIp_TxCallback(port,(uint16)sentbytes);
}
```

I created a server side program for receiving data from the client and sending the response back to the client. I don't know where is the mistake in the above program, I am not able to receive data from the client and there is no response back to the client. Client is a tool for sending the data to the specified port and ip address.

NOTE: Client will be keep on sending the data.
Could anyone help me in this ?

Comment: `I am not able to recieve data from the client and there is no response back to the client` . your `bind` is successful or not?

Comment: Have you verified that the client is actually sending packages? A package analyzer like wireshark will see them.

Comment: yes!!! I checked it and also I can recieve it in recvfrom api. There is nothing in the sendto api :(